# Access violation calling Win API from C# using DllImport

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

The task is to determine the last write time for the registry key. As standard RegistryKey class doesn't provide this feature, I have to use WinAPI function "RegQueryInfoKey". To get the key handle I open it by "RegOpenKeyEx".

This is the WinAPI prototype of the function (taken from MSDN):

```
LONG WINAPI RegOpenKeyEx(
  __in          HKEY hKey,
  __in          LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
                DWORD ulOptions,
  __in          REGSAM samDesired,
  __out         PHKEY phkResult
);
```

I use the following declaration:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(UIntPtr hkey, string lpSubKey, uint samDesired, ref UIntPtr phkResult);
```

Then I call it in the following way:

```
UIntPtr hKey = UIntPtr.Zero;
string myKeyName = "blablabla";
UIntPtr HKEY_USERS = (UIntPtr)0x80000003; 
uint KEY_READ = 0x20019;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_USERS, myKeyName, KEY_READ, ref hKey);
```

At this point I get "Access violation" exception. What am I doing wrong? 
I think something is wrong with parameters passing, but how to do it right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 5 parameters in the native function's prototype, and only 4 in your P/Invoke signature.

In particular, you're missing `DWORD ulOptions`. This parameter is "reserved and must be zero" according to the MSDN documentation, but it must still be passed in the function call.

Also, you don't need to set the [`SetLastError` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx) because the `RegOpenKeyEx` function *returns* its error code; you don't have to retrieve it by calling `GetLastError`. Consequently, you don't need the marshaler to save that value for you automatically. Just check the return value for the error code.

Change your P/Invoke signature to look like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(UIntPtr hkey, string lpSubKey,
                                      uint ulOptions, uint samDesired,
                                      out UIntPtr phkResult);
```

The wrong P/Invoke signature is almost always the cause of "access violation" errors. When you see one of those, make sure you double-check it twice!

Answer (score 4):

You've missed `ulOptions` from your P/Invoke signature.